# Amazon Command Line Tools Sync on Linux is very slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use Amazon Command Line Tools to sync a bucket with a folder on my Centos Server. I installed the aws cli, set up the config, and ran:

```
aws s3 sync s3://my.bucket/sounds/ /var/lib/folder/sounds/
```

The problem is that it was just terrible... very very very slow downloads, with almost all failed (maybe 1 file worked). It was showing:

```
ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

almost all the time.

So, as a control test, i ran the same thing on a windows box within the exact same cabinet. (oh, by the way, its hosted on 50MB/s fibre, so its very very fast).
It synced in seconds!

I found s3cmd - this was more sucessfull (all the files actually synced) but it gives a summary at the end - the rate i got was 12KB/s! Ouch!

Clearly something is up with my machine/config/python/ not sure what.

If I look at the debug of the Amazon Command Line Tool - i see it complaining about an SSL file being at EOF, and then from then on it shows:

```
File "/usr/local/aws/lib/python2.6/site-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/response.py", line 267, in read
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.')
```

I'm running Centos 6.5 with Python 2.6. (I have no clue about Python.) Any ideas about what could be causing this?

Edit: 
After guessing that it could be Python that's the issue, i installed 3.3 and re-installed the awscli, but it does exactly the same thing.

```
aws-cli/1.9.16 Python/3.3.3 Linux/2.6.32-358.6.2.el6.x86_64 botocore/1.3.16
```

It downloads one file, that seems to block the downloads of all the other files, so they all timeout.

Comment: What version of the CLI are you using? The aws s3 sync command is fairly memory intensive. Can you confirm the instance isn't under other significant memory pressure during this operation?

Comment: Its our test box, so no, doing absolutely nothing. The cli was wget'ed from their server maybe yesterday - no idea what version. Was just following their set-up help file. Its not a performance issue - i repeated the same commands on other linux boxes (same kind of setup) same results.

Comment: I think its to do with Python and how it (or the Amazon code) connects to their servers. Something to do with SSL connections